# Create custom Observable is needed when use headers on generic method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, ionic4

I have created a generic service like so.

*common.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  post(url: string, params: any): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) };
      this.http.post(url, params, httpOptions)
        .subscribe(response => {
          observer.next(response);
          observer.complete();
        }, (err) => {
          observer.error(err);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

my-service.ts

```
 book(data: Spa): Observable<any> {
    return this.commonService.post(`${environment.apiURL}/my/v3/my.json`, data);
  }
```

*page.ts*

```
  book() {
     this.myService.book(spa).subscribe((res: any) => {
      }, error => { console.log(error); });
     }
  }
```

**Q:** Do I need to create a custom `Observable` on `post()` method? Since `this.http.post(url, params, httpOptions)` returns `Observable` hope I do not need to create custom `Observable` again no (i.e. `common.ts`)?

*Note:* Above works fine and no errors though.

Comment: no you do not, just return `return http.post(....` also see this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/when-to-subscribe-a83332ae053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function post returns an observable and it could be typed if you want it, then you don't need to create another observable for that you can simplify like:

```
post(url: string, params: any): Observable<any> {
   const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) };
   return this.http.post(url, params, httpOptions);
}
```